# Adding new element with child nodes Xml and C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

I have a windows form application I am writing and I want to create an xml file and add data to it.

The code is below.

```
 xmlFile = new XDocument(
                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                    new XComment("XML File for storing " + RootName));
xmlFile.Add(new XElement(RootName));

// Loop through the list and create a new element for each item in the list
foreach (Contact c in contactsList)
{
    try
    {
        xmlFile.Add(new XElement("Contact",
            new XElement("Name", c.Name),
            new XElement("Email", c.EmailAddress),
            new XElement("Mobile Number", c.MobileNumber),
            new XElement("Mobile Carrier", c.sMobileCarrier)
            )
        );
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR WITH NEW ELEMENTS");
    }
}
xmlFile.Save(FileName);
```

When I run the program, the try block throws and error and I get the message box error.
When I debug, the program says the exception has to do with:

```
The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
```

I am not sure what this means, because I checked all the values being passed in and upto the point of entry, there is something there.

Am I missing a parameter in the `xmlFile.Add()` statement?

One last question, when I insert the Root element after creating the XDocument object,
in the file it comes out as `<Contacts />`, which I want to be the closing root tag.

How do I get the starting tag inserted, and then when I go to save at the end, it appends the closing tag?

Thanks

Update---------------------
Thanks to MarcinJuraszek, I was able to get past that exception being thrown, but now i get this error:

```
This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
```

Any ideas what that means or what is causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear: XML element name cannot contain space. You're trying to do exactly that:

```
        new XElement("Mobile Number", c.MobileNumber),
        new XElement("Mobile Carrier", c.sMobileCarrier)
```

Change these lines to not contain spaces and it should work. e.g.

```
        new XElement("MobileNumber", c.MobileNumber),
        new XElement("MobileCarrier", c.sMobileCarrier)
```

> How do I get the starting tag inserted, and then when I go to save at the end, it appends the closing tag?

Don't worry about starting/closing tags. `XElement.Save` method will take care of that.

***Update***

The second problem here is a fact, that you're trying to create document with multiple root elements. That's because instead of adding new content into root `XElement` you're trying to add it directly into `XDocument` instance.

Try following:

```
    xmlFile.Root.Add(new XElement("Contact",
        new XElement("Name", c.Name),
        new XElement("Email", c.EmailAddress),
        new XElement("MobileNumber", c.MobileNumber),
        new XElement("MobileCarrier", c.sMobileCarrier)
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I am getting a different error. Any ideas on that one?